# Issue with using generic function to test whether list of models has any entries or is null

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to use a generic function to simplify some code... the purpose of the function is to test whether or not a list, normally a list of models, passed to it has any entries or is null... when I attempt to use the function I wrote, it gives me the error:

> The type `List<FooBarModel>` cannot be used as a type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method `HasEntries<T>(T)`. There is no implicit reference conversion from `List<FooBarModel>` to `List<List<FooBarModel>>`...

I'm not quite sure how to write the generic function appropriately...

My function is as follows:

```
    private static bool HasEntries<T>(T toTest) where T : List<T>
    {
        return toTest?.Any() ?? false;
    }
```

and I'm calling it by doing the following:

```
if (PricingPublicationController.HasEntries(weeWoo))
{
    // code code code
}
```

where weeWoo is of type:

```
List<FooBarModel>();
```

Edit:
To clarify, FooBarModel and other things taking the place of T would normally be a class model for MVC

Comment: I'm assuming this is a typo - I suspect you meant `private static bool HasEntries<T>(List<T> toTest) { ... }`. I'm sure you can see why `T: List<T>` (T must be assignable to List<T>) might pose a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your generic type constraint is wrong.

`where T : List<T>` means: `T` must be a `List` of `T`. But in fact your `T` is a `List` of *something*, not of `T`.

Here is a better solution:

```
bool HasEntries<T>(T toTest) where T : IList
{
  return toTest?.Count > 0;
}
```

It is even faster, because it uses the `Count` property directly, without LINQ.

Answer (score 2):

Create the method as:

```
private static bool HasEntries<T>(List<T> toTest)
{
    return toTest?.Any() ?? false;
}
```

Comment: Does `T` have to be class for some reason? What if OP wanted a list of `int`?

Comment: Don't need to be, but the OP said his T is actually a POCO. So I put it as a class.

Comment: The OP doesn't tell what the `FooBarModel` is. Maybe it's a `struct`.

Comment: @Azhar If you remove the condition, it will work for lists of reference and value types.

Comment: restriction of T removed.

Comment: This works correctly for me! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct, but if you want to make it a little more useful, you could write an extension method like this:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
        return !(sequence?.Any() ?? false);
    }
}
```

You can now use it on *anything* that is enumerable, whether it's an array, a list or an actual `IEnumerable<T>` of unknown origin.

So instead of

```
if (PricingPublicationController.HasEntries(weeWoo))
```

you would write:

```
if (!weeWoo.IsNullOrEmpty())
```